# Can't get my head around "Injector already created, can not register a module!" error

Tags: angularjs

My application seems to run fine. I started writing test cases and got the dreaded **Injector already created, can not register a module!** error.

Here's my test code.  These are the only lines in the file.

```
'use strict';

var fac,
    osf,
    obff;

beforeEach(module("myApp"));

beforeEach(inject(function (OrderSashingFactory) {
    fac = OrderSashingFactory;
}));
```

I really don't know where to go from here - I am going in circles.

EDIT - here's my `karma.conf.js` file. I have other tests that run fine.

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Aug 25 2014 21:08:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/js/*.js',
            'app/test/js/*.js',
            'app/partials/**/*.html'
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'app/partials/**/*.html' : 'html2js'
        },

        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            // strip app from the file path
            stripPrefix: 'app/'
        },

        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [

        ],

//        plugins: [
//            'karma-mocha',
//            'karma-chrome-launcher'
//        ],


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // Start these browsers, currently available:
        // - Chrome
        // - ChromeCanary
        // - Firefox
        // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
        // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
        // - PhantomJS
        // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
        browsers: ['Chrome'],


        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        captureTimeout: 60000,


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you show us your karma.conf.js if any ?

Comment: You haven't wrapped your test in `describe('Foo', /* your function with the given code */);` could it be the problem ?

Comment: That would be the problem. I spent hours looking at my injectors :-/

Comment: @aduch Could you post your comment as an answer so that it stands out more? Your comment was the right solution for me as well.

Comment: @AtesGoral There you go :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You haven't wrapped your test in a `describe`, it would look something like this:

```
describe('MyTestName', function () { 
    'use strict';

    var fac,
        osf,
        obff;

    beforeEach(module("myApp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function (OrderSashingFactory) {
        fac = OrderSashingFactory;
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are mixing calls to `module('someApp')` and `inject($someDependency)` you will get this error.

All your calls to `module('someApp')` must occur before your calls to  `inject($someDependency)`.

Comment: Can you provide us with an example ?

Answer (score 1):

To add on top of that answer from @axelduch, i had an issue where another file would not have the describe in, and that's what was causing my **Injector already created, can not register a module!**

If you run your tests with many files linked like this (this is using requirejs)

```
define(["require", "exports", "./test1.tests", "./test2.tests"], function (require, exports, Test1, Test2) {
    describe("Test Module", function () {
        Test1.tests();
        Test2.tests();
    });
});
```

Then ensure EACH tests that are run in this describe here **contains their own describe method** in them. So for example, the Test1 file would look like this

```
    function tests() {
        describe("Test directive", function () {
            beforeEach(function () {
            });
            afterEach(function () {
            });
        });
    }
```

Ensure all your linked tests file within the scope of your test **has their own describe method**, otherwise you may not know it but it's another test that makes your unit test fail.. and It can take you a long time to realize it.

Answer (score 1):

This can also mean you have something like the following:

```
inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $document, $timeout) {
   // Code processing inject
});

module(function($provide) {
   // Provide code
})
```

That is wrong, the test runner will not allow you to do it in this order as its already busy injecting and you are past the phase for setting up provides.

The correct way of course is:

```
module(function($provide) {
   // Provide code
})

inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $document, $timeout) {
   // Code processing inject
});
```

ensure you have it in the right order.